# No me devuelve los valores de los punteros luego de operacion logica

Tags: c

Tengo 2 archivos un ft_div_mod.c y un main.c. El primero contiene la funcion y en el main doy valores a int a e int b el cual realiza una division y apunta el cociente y el resto en 2 punteros distintos. Compilo sin errores pero me lanza el siguiente error  al ejecutar el codigo[1] 9803 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out

Mi ft_div_mod.c

```
void    ft_div_mod(int a, int b, int *div, int *mod)
{
*div = a / b;
*mod = a % b;
}
```

Mi main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void    ft_div_mod(int a, int b, int *div, int *mod);

 int main()
 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int *div;
    int *mod;

    a = 15;
    b = 2;

    ft_div_mod(a, b, div, mod);

    printf("Cociente es: %ls\n", div);
    printf("Resto es: %ls\n", mod);
 }
```

He probado a llamar a &div y &mod pero me lanza warnings y me sigue lanzando el mismo error de arriba mencionado

*Edit ya lo arregle he quitado puntero de div y mod y los llame ft_div_mod con &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo suyo es que en la llamada a la función pases la dirección del puntero:

```
ft_div_mod(a, b, &div, &mod);
```

Comment: No puedes pasar la dirección de memoria de un puntero en los dos últimos parámetros de la función `fit_div_mod`, porqué el parámetro se lo declaró como un puntero simple, es decir, en realidad los parámetros `div` y `mod` esperan la dirección de memoria de un dato, no la de un puntero. Lo único que provoca esto, es que la función asigne un dato entero hacia el puntero que pasaste por referencia y esto no tiene ningún sentido, el puntero `div` o `mod` (del main) lo que esperan es una dirección válida del programa, no un número entero cualquiera.

Comment: El problema radica cuando trates de desreferenciar el puntero que pasaste por referencia, dará un fallo de segmentación, por esa razón no se recomienda su uso, ya que estarías utilizando los punteros de forma insegura.

Answer (score 2):

> > Compilo sin errores pero me lanza el siguiente error al ejecutar el codigo[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/core-dump-segmentation-fault-c-cpp/) 9803 segmentation fault (core dumped) ./a.out

El error se debe porqué nunca has inicializado los punteros `div` y `mod`. Cuando el programa se ejecute, ambos punteros tendrán un espacio de memoria; sin embargo, el problema radica que en su región de memoria habrá un dato basura. Entonces cuando ejecutes esta función:

```
ft_div_mod(a, b, div, mod);
```

Le estarías pasando datos basura a los dos últimos parámetros, que a su vez, podrían ser direcciones de memoria que no le pertenecen al programa, entonces cuando esta instrucción se ejecute:

```
*div = a / b;
```

Te dará un [fallo de segmentación](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/core-dump-segmentation-fault-c-cpp/) porqué estás intentando escribir un dato en una dirección que el programa no tiene acceso. Por esa razón tu programa dejaría de funcionar.

Una posible solución es declarando dos variables extras para poder guardar los resultados del cociente y residuo. Adicionalmente, se deberá asignar la dirección de memoria de esas variables a los punteros `div` y `mod`.

Ejemplo:

```
int main()
 {
    int a;
    int b;

    //En estas dos variables se guardan los resultados.
    int rdiv;
    int rmod;
    //Se asigna la dirección de cada variable donde se almacenan el resultado.
    int *div = &rdiv;
    int *mod = &rmod;
    a = 15;
    b = 2;

    ft_div_mod(a, b, div, mod);
    //Para imprimir el cociente y resto, se debe usar el operador de desreferencia (*)
    printf("Cociente es: %d\n", *div);
    printf("Resto es: %d\n", *mod);

    return 0;
 }
```

De este modo no ocurrirá fallo de segmentación porqué se le estaría pasando a los últimos parámetros una dirección que si le pertenece al programa, en la cual podrá acceder sin problemas.

Otra forma de solucionar este problema, es pasando directamente la dirección de memoria de las variables `rdiv` y `rmod`a los dos últimos parámetros de la función y por ende, eliminarías los punteros `div` y `mod`.

Ejemplo:

```
 int main()
 {
    int a;
    int b;

    int rdiv;
    int rmod;

    a = 15;
    b = 2;

    ft_div_mod(a, b, &rdiv, &rmod);

    printf("Cociente es: %d\n", rdiv);
    printf("Resto es: %d\n", rmod);

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que no estas inicializando el puntero `int *div`, un puntero no inicializado puede apuntar a cualquier cosa, esto puede variar según el compilador que utilices, una buena practica es que cada vez que definas un apuntador declares su valor a NULL `int *div = NULL;`.

Otra cosa importante es que al trabajar con un puntero NULL, si quieres modificar el contenido de dicho puntero al pasarlo como parámetro a una función, debes hacerlo a través de un doble apuntador, ya que, el objetivo es modificar el apuntador reservando memoria según el tipo, en este caso de tipo **int** y eso se logra con un puntero doble.

Siempre que reserves memoria con **malloc**, **calloc** o **realloc** debes liberar la memoria reservada con la función **free**.

***main.c***

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 15;
    int b = 2;

    int *div = NULL;
    int *mod = NULL;

    ft_div_mod(a, b, &div, &mod);

    if (div != NULL) {
        printf("Cociente es: %d\n", *div);
        free(div);
        div = NULL;
    }

    if (mod != NULL) {
        printf("Resto es: %d\n", *mod);
        free(mod);
        mod = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***ft_div_mod.c***

```c
void ft_div_mod(int a, int b, int **div, int **mod)
{
    if ((*div) == NULL)
        (*div) = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));

    if ((*mod) == NULL)
        (*mod) = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));

    if ((*div) != NULL) *(*div) = (a / b);
    if ((*mod) != NULL) *(*mod) = (a % b);
}
```

Comment: En la parte del `main` ocurrirá un fallo de segmentación cuando se intente imprimir los resultados y esto pasaría cuando el puntero `div` o `mod` apunten a `NULL`. En la función `ft_div_mod` también puede ocurrir fallo de segmentación en esta línea: `*(*div) = (a / b);` Esto pasará cuando `malloc` no pueda asignar memoria y hará que el puntero que hayas pasado por referencia se quede apuntando a `NULL` y ahí es donde tu programa dejaría de funcionar.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, edite el código para evitar esos segmentation fault @MrDave1999